# Type hints for a function that accepts a (homogeneous) sequence of one of several types

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

I'm trying to provide type hints for a function that accepts a sequence
with one of two `type`s of elements, and I'm at a loss how to make `mypy` happy.  Please note, the sequence is homogeneous, meaning the types can't be mixed, either-or.  Usually I do this when they are "compatible" types, e.g. a path `str` or a `pathlib.Path` object, and annotating that with `Union` works just fine.  But in the case of a sequence, `Sequence[Union[..]]` (or `Union[Sequence[..]]`) doesn't seem to work.  Here's a minimal working example:

```
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Sequence, Dict, Union


def fn_accepts_dict(adict):
    """Function from an external module that accepts `dict`s."""
    for key, val in adict.items():
        print(f"{key}, {val}")


def vararg_test(resources: Sequence[Union[str, Dict]]):
    """My function where I want to provide type hints"""
    if isinstance(resources[0], str):
        resources2 = [{"path": Path(f)} for f in resources]
    else:
        resources2 = resources
    for d in resources2:
        fn_accepts_dict(d)
```

Now, with the above definitions, calling `vararg_test` with either of
these two work as expected:

```
l1 = ["foo/bar", "bar/baz"]
l2 = [{"path": Path("foo/bar")}, {"path": Path("bar/baz")}]
```

But running `mypy` gives me the following errors:

```
type_hints.py:14: error: Argument 1 to "Path" has incompatible type "Union[str, Dict[Any, Any]]"; expected "Union[str, _PathLike[str]]"
type_hints.py:16: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Sequence[Union[str, Dict[Any, Any]]]", variable has type "List[Dict[str, Path]]")
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

How can I resolve this?

**Edit**:
To give some background, the `str` is a path, and the `dict` has metadata corresponding to that path, and the function `fn_accepts_dict` collates metadata into one metadata object.  So they logical flow is either: `str -> dict -> fn_accepts_dict` or, `dict -> fn_accepts_dict`.

While @ShadowRanger's suggestion looked promising, no luck.  I get the same error with the following hints:

```
def vararg_test2(resources: Union[Sequence[str], Sequence[Dict]]):
    ... # same implementation as above
```

`mypy` error:

```
type_hints.py:24: error: Argument 1 to "Path" has incompatible type "Union[str, Dict[Any, Any]]"; expected "Union[str, _PathLike[str]]"
type_hints.py:26: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Union[Sequence[str], Sequence[Dict[Any, Any]]]", variable has type "List[Dict[str, Path]]")
```

**Edit 2**:  unfortunately, with all the annotations, it looks more like C/C++ than Python; see my [own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60247259/289784) below for a much more Pythonic solution.

Comment: Try moving the `Union` out a level? `Union[Sequence[str], Sequence[Dict]]`? Looks like you actually pass a homogeneous sequence of one type or the other anyway. Not necessarily a fix if you want to accept heterogeneous sequences though.

Comment: Such a heterogenous sequence won't work with the desired usage, since `Path` can't take a `dict` as an argument.

Comment: Specifically, just because `resource[0]` is a `str` doesn't mean *every* element of `resources` is a `str` that can be passed to `Path`. As written, ShadowRanger's suggest to pass a union of homogenous sequences is correct. If you really want a heterogeneous sequence, you'll need to test each element individually.

Comment: @ShadowRanger nice idea, unfortunately didn't work.  And you are right, it's a homogeneous sequence.  I have edited the question to clarify that point.

Comment: Take note that as far as I can tell, your code is well-typed. ``mypy`` is failing to properly connect the individual type constraints. With ``resources: Union[Sequence[str], Sequence[Dict]]``, ``isinstance(resources[0], str)`` does strictly exclude the union's second case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: `mypy` [only understands](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/master/test-data/unit/check-isinstance.test) `isinstance(v, tp)` with respect to `v`. It does not understand `isinstance(v<expr>, tp)` with respect to `v`, e.g. `v[0]: str` implying the type of `v: List[str]`.

---

`mypy` doesn't understand `isinstance(resources[0], str)` to branch between `resources: Sequence[str]` and `resources: Sequence[Dict]`. This means that `resources = resources2` infers both to be the *exact* same type, which either breaks on assigning or using `resources2`.

You must annotate `resources2` to prevent inferred type equality, and `cast` in the branches to mark them as such.

```
def vararg_test(resources: Union[Sequence[str], Sequence[Dict]]):
    """My function where I want to provide type hints"""
    resources2: Sequence[Dict]  # fixed type to prevent inferred equality
    if isinstance(resources[0], str):  # Mypy does not recognise this branch by itself!
        # exclude second Union branch
        resources = cast(Sequence[str], resources)
        resources2 = [{"path": Path(f)} for f in resources]
    else:
        # exclude first Union branch
        resources2 = cast(Sequence[Dict], resources)
    for d in resources2:
        fn_accepts_dict(d)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I understand.  But strangely it only resolves the first error.  The 2nd `cast` doesn't seem to work!  (please see my edit)

Comment: @suvayu Did you annotate ``resources2`` at the start of the function? The error message implies otherwise.

Comment: Ah, rt!  I missed that!  Thank you, I'll fix my 2nd edit, and accept your answer!

Comment: Hi, I found a way to make this much more Pythonic, without any need for additional type annotations or `cast`s: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60247259/289784

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend *not* trying to do two different things in one function, based on the type of the argument. Define two different functions instead, each taking a specific type of sequence.

```
def do_with_strings(resources: Sequence[str]):
    do_with_dicts([{"path": Path(f)} for f in resources])


def do_with_dicts(resources: Sequence[dict]):
    for d in resources:
        fn_accepts_dict(d)
```

---

For your code as written, the type of `resources` has to be, as ShadowRanger suggested in the comments, `Union[Sequence[str],Sequence[dict]]`, since you assume that the entire list has the same type as the first element.

If you want to keep the heterogenous type, you need to check each and every element to determine it needs to be turned into a `dict`:

```
def vararg_test(resources: Sequence[Union[str, Dict]]):
    for f in resources:
        if isinstance(f, str):
            f = {"path": Path(f)}
        fn_accepts_dict(f)
```

Comment: @ShadowRanger is right, I am only passing homogeneous sequences, and the function isn't doing different things, just adding an extra step when it's a string.  Please see my edit of the question for more clarification.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @MisterMiyagi's answer, the issue stems from `mypy` not being able to infer the types when an expression is used in `isinstance`.  So I tried an alternative implementation where `isinstance` is passed a name.  This also had the benefit that `vararg_test` could now accept any iterable.

```
def vararg_test(resources: Iterable[Union[str, Dict]]):
    """My function where I want to use type hints"""
    resources2: List[Dict] = []
    for res in resources:
        if isinstance(res, str):
            res = {"path": Path(res)}
        resources2 += [res]
    for d in resources2:
        fn_accepts_dict(d)
```

However this still requires us to annotate `resources2`, but it's easy to reformulate as list comprehension where we wouldn't need any annotations.

```
def vararg_test3(resources: Iterable[Union[str, Dict]]):
    """My function where I want to use type hints"""
    resources2 = [
        {"path": Path(res)} if isinstance(res, str) else res
        for res in resources
    ]
    for d in resources2:
        fn_accepts_dict(d)
```